# How do I identify a UITextFiled apart from tags

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Went through similar questions and `tags` is basically the answer to all of them. The issue is I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has two text fields first name and last name. In my app I have a `+` button which when clicked add a new row to the table view and the table view reloads. Now earlier if a user typed something and then clicked the `+` button a new row would get added but the first and last name in the first row would disappear. To fix this I took a `NSMutableArray`, say `fNameArray` and would add the what the user types in `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField reason:(UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)reason` This works well but now I have to create another  `NSMutableArray` for last name and the issue is I don't know how will I identify the textfield in the above delegate. Currently I am setting the tags in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as `cell.tf_firstName.tag = indexPath.row;`

Answer (score 0):

The `tag` property won't work if the same tag value is assigned to more than one text field AND the same delegate is used for all text fields.

Below is an implementation that solves this problem by using a *different* delegate for each set of text fields.

The `TextFieldArrayManager` manages an array of text fields and their data. It acts as the delegate for the text fields it manages.

```
@interface TextFieldArrayManager : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property NSMutableArray *textItems;
@end

@implementation TextFieldArrayManager
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (_textItems.count >= textField.tag + 1) {
        if (textField.text) {
            _textItems[textField.tag] = textField.text;
        }
        else {
            _textItems[textField.tag] = @"";
        }
    }
}
@end
```

The view controller uses a separate `TextFieldArrayManager` to manage the first and last names.

```
@interface ObjcTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation ObjcTableViewController

TextFieldArrayManager *firstNames;
TextFieldArrayManager *lastNames;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstNames = [[TextFieldArrayManager alloc] init];
    firstNames.textItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"George", @"Ludwig", @"Wolfgang", nil];

    lastNames = [[TextFieldArrayManager alloc] init];
    lastNames.textItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Handel", @"Beethoven", @"Mozart", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return firstNames.textItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ObjcTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.firstName.delegate = firstNames;
    cell.firstName.text = firstNames.textItems[indexPath.row];
    cell.firstName.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.lastName.delegate = lastNames;
    cell.lastName.text = lastNames.textItems[indexPath.row];
    cell.lastName.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

To add a new, empty row to the table, you can do this:

```
[firstNames.textItems addObject:@""];
[lastNames.textItems addObject:@""];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

When the user enters text, it will be saved to the textItems.